# how do I make an optional block parameter for use with a CCSequence?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

basically I want to do this:

```
-(void)doIt:(void(^)())block {

    [CCSequence *sequence = [CCSequence actions:
                              [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:1.0f], 
                              (block ? [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:block] : nil), nil];

    [self runAction:sequence];

}
```

So that I can do:

```
[self doIt:^{ [self somethingElse]; }];
```

as well as:

```
[self doIt:nil];
```

rather than having to do when I have no need for a callback:

```
[self doIt:^{}];
```

...  Any suggestions on how to do this sort of thing?

Answer (score 1):

You could just check to make sure the block exists with

```
if(block)
{
    //Sequence with block
}
else
{
    //Sequence without block
}
```